# Storing objects in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a small issue when I run into while using arraylists in Java. Essentially I am hoping to store an array in an arraylist. I know that arraylists can hold objects, so it should be possible, but I am not sure how.

For the most part my arraylist (which is parsed from a file) is just holding one character as a string, but once in a while it has a series of characters, like this:

```
    myarray
0    a
1    a
2    d
3    g
4    d
5    f,s,t
6    r
```

Most of the time the only character I would care about in the string residing at position 5 is the f but occasionally I may need to look at the s or the t as well. My solution to this is to make an array like this:

```
      subarray
0     f 
1     s
2     t
```

and store subarray in position 5 instead.

```
    myarray
0    a
1    a
2    d
3    g
4    d
5    subarray[f,s,t]
6    r
```

I tried to do this with this code:

```
 //for the length of the arraylist
 for(int al = 0; al < myarray.size(); al++){
      //check the size of the string
      String value = myarray.get(al);
      int strsz = value.length();
      prse = value.split(dlmcma);
      //if it is bigger than 1 then use a subarray
      if(strsz > 1){
          subarray[0] = prse[0];
          subarray[1] = prse[1];
          subarray[2] = prse[2];
      }
      //set subarray to the location of the string that was too long
      //this is where it all goes horribly wrong
      alt4.set(al, subarray[]);
  }
```

This isn't working the way I would like though. It won't allow me to .set(int, array). It only allows .set(int, string). Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: what is alt4 (object declaration)?

Comment: You do realize that a String is a char[] with methods around, right? Just use a List<String> with values like "a" or "fst", there's no need for separators and splitting if what you're interested in is individual characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to have an ArrayList of ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> alt4 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

However, this probably isn't the best solution.  You may want to rethink your data model and look for a better solution.

Comment: Yeah. I will be rethinking it today. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change `alt4.set(al, subarray[]);` to

```
         alt4.add(subarray);
```

I assume `alt4` is another defined `ArrayList<String[]>`. If not, define it as below:

```
        List<String[]> alt4= new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

or

```
        ArrayList<String[]> alt4= new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are declaring alt4 as `List<String>` and that's why it is not letting you set an array of String as a list element.  You should declare it as `List<String[]>` and is each element is only singular, simply set it as the 0th element of the String[] array before adding it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to:

```
List<List<Character>> alt4 = new ArrayList<List<Character>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want to get

```
public class Tester {

    List<String> myArrays = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "a", "d", "g", "d", "f,s,t", "r" });

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> alt4 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    private void manageArray() {
        // for the length of the arraylist
        ArrayList<String> subarray = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int al = 0; al < myArrays.size(); al++) {
            // check the size of the string
            String value = myArrays.get(al);
            int strsz = value.length();
            String prse[] = value.split(",");
            // if it is bigger than 1 then use a subarray
            if(strsz > 1) {
                for(String string : prse) {
                    subarray.add(string);
                }
            }
            // set subarray to the location of the string that was too long
            // this is where it all goes horribly wrong
            alt4.set(al, subarray);
        }

    }
}
```